# Why isn't $1$ a superior highly composite number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, divisor-sum

A [*superior highly composite number*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superior_highly_composite_number) is a positive integer $n$ for which there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $\dfrac{d(n)}{n^\epsilon} \geq \dfrac{d(k)}{k^\epsilon}$ for all $k>1$, where the function $d(n)$ counts the divisors of $n$.

The first superior highly composite numbers are $2, 6, 12, 60, 120, 360, 2520, 5040, 55440, \dots$

.

Edit: Bump. I am still looking for answers.

Comment: $1$ is not a composite number.  Nor is $2$.

Comment: @Henry: A composite number and a highly composite number are two completely different things... And both 1 and 2 are highly composite numbers.

Comment: +1 for interesting question. The only pattern difference I see is the parity (1 is odd, all others are even). However, I can't say that that is the reason.

Comment: My best guess is that the definition actually says "there is an $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$" (and wikipedia lost the $< 1$ restriction), and then $1$ doesn't fit the bill. Or that $1$ is explicitly excluded, and wikipedia forgot that.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: I looked into other articles (OEIS, WolframMathWorld, etc...), and they are all similar to the Wikipedia article: they all say "for which there is an $\epsilon > 0$", and not "for which there is an $\epsilon ∈$ $]0,1[$".

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be the first time that I guess wrong. Problem is, however, that for $\varepsilon \geqslant 1$, the condition is fulfilled for $n = 1$, but all the pages agree that the first superior holy confessionless nutrient is $2$, so **something** would have to exclude $1$. (Yes, that is your question, I know.)

Comment: Geez, this phrasing is horrible. The scope of the quantifier are so confusing...

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be found in Ramanujan's original [paper](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2_14/1/347).
He gives the following theorem:

> If $N$ is a [highly composite number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number), and $N = 2^{a_2} \times \dots \times p_1^{a_{p_1}}$ be its prime factorization, then $a_{p_1}=1$ except for $N=4$ and $N=36$.

This theorem fails if $N=1$ is considered to be highly composite (however theorem may not make sense if $N=1$).
His definition of highly composite number is verbatim:

> A number $N$ may be said to be a highly composite number, if
>   $d(N') < d(N)$ for all values of $N’$ less than $N$.

With this definition $1$ should be highly composite, but $1$ does not appear in his list of highly composite numbers.
So I suppose the author is implicitly considering numbers with at least one prime divisor (i.e. for which $p_1$ make sense in all his proofs).
Same reason for why $1$ is not superior highly composite.

Comment: A version of the paper can be accessed without the paywall at http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram15.html (there appear to be some minor typos, however, in that "less than" is typeset twice as "less that" where "superior highly composite number" is defined).

Comment: Because that would make 1 both prime and composite at the same time.